# LOOKUP pickle in Google sheets (adding different payments from different clients and splitting them by month)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, vlookup, textjoin

I have an issue with the use of LOOKUP formulas for this example:

[image]

I am trying to determine a way to add different payments from different clients by month

[This is the worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QRMvao4lC89jbkpjE1zImO687ahSAGLO_nLPdhnj_UI/edit?usp=sharing) and the information **in blue** is the desired result (which I am trying to automate).

Can someone shine a light as to which formulas to use, and how to accomplish that given I am separating the payments made from each client by month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B6&C3:G3, {C10:C&TEXT(B10:B, "mmmm"), D10:D}, 2, )))
```

[image]

or if you want zeros:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B6&C3:G3, {C10:C&TEXT(B10:B, "mmmm"), D10:D}, 2, ))*1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello player0, I just spotted something in your answer. If you look at Client 2 month of August, the total is $360. In other works, it is not adding all the payments for that month per client (just getting the first one). Would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: @bru1987 try changing `{C10:C&TEXT(B10:B, "mmmm"), D10:D}` to `QUERY({C10:C&TEXT(B10:B, "mmmm"), D10:D}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", )`

Comment: Hello @player0! Ever since your interaction with me in this post, I've used your macro and it works flawlessly. I wonder, since we now hit a new year (and a new November), if you can help me make it work for years to come (it stopped counting this month). I'm updating the link in the post. I deeply appreciate your help. Thank you